# ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable on Safari with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari

I've been getting an error that is puzzling me. The error is `ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable.` and refers to the line `const app = createApp(App)`:

```
// main.js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from 'components/App.vue';

// ...

const app = createApp(App);
```

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <template v-if="!started">
    <Start @started="start" />
  </template>
  <template v-else-if="!loaded">
    <Loading @loaded="loaded = true" />
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <Tip />
    <Cutscene v-if="state.phase == 'INTRO'" />
    <Interstitial v-if="state.phase == 'INTERSTITIAL'" />
    <Planning v-if="state.phase == 'PLANNING'" />
    <Stream v-else-if="state.phase == 'EVENTS'" />
    <Report v-else-if="state.phase == 'REPORT'" />
    <End :lose="true" v-else-if="state.phase == 'GAMEOVER'" />
    <End :lose="false" v-else-if="state.phase == 'GAMEWIN'" />
  </template>
</template>

<script>
import debug from '/src/debug';
import state from '/src/state';
import Tip from './tip/Tip.vue';
import Start from './Start.vue';
import Loading from './Loading.vue';
import End from './phases/End.vue';
import Cutscene from './phases/Cutscene.vue';
import Interstitial from './phases/Interstitial.vue';
import Report from './phases/Report.vue';
import Stream from './phases/events/Events.vue';
import Planning from './phases/planning/Planning.vue';
import AudioManager from '/src/audio/manager';

// Hacky
window.audioManager = new AudioManager();
if (!state.sound) {
  window.audioManager.muted = true;
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      state,
      started: false,
      loaded: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      this.started = true;
    }
  },
  components: {
    Tip,
    Start,
    Report,
    Stream,
    Planning,
    End,
    Loading,
    Cutscene,
    Interstitial,
  },
}
</script>
```

I've stared at this a long time and it seems like all my variables are properly initialized. Looking at my logging, this error seems to only occur with Safari (mobile and desktop). I can't tell if this is specifically Vue-related or what. I'm using Vue 3.1.4.

Comment: So this only happens in Safari?

Comment: Mostly--43.5% of occurrences are on desktop Safari, 42.75% on mobile Safari, 1.3% on "Mobile Safari UI", and 5.34% on Apple Mail, which I assume uses an embedded Safari browser? So that's almost 93% total. The rest look like they may be iOS webkit views as well.

Comment: What I meant was, other browsers work fine?

Comment: Yes, I haven't encountered the issue with other browsers.

Comment: what if you `console.log(App)` just before that line - I'm assuming safari gets it wrong with `App` not `app` ... also, don't always believe the console for which line causes the error ... check the code you haven't posted - put some console.log in amongst the code, see where execution stops

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was assigning the output of createApp to an exported variable and then importing and using it in another .ts file.

A workaround that avoids this bug is to use:

```js
import { vueApp } from "./main";
const getVueApp = () => ((window as any).app as typeof vueApp);
```

After previously creating your app like so:

```js
const app = createApp(App);
(window as any).app = app;
```

Then you can call something like `getVueApp().$nextTick` with no issues.

If don't use TypeScript, you can simply just reference `window.app` directly, the import and function wrapper are just to get proper type inference!

Comment: In the hindsight, you can also just define and export `getVueApp` in your main file, and then just import it normally in any other module, also avoids this issue